# Laravel: Is there a way to get a model's relationship with another table for any given fieldname?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a scenario where I want to provide a list of fields of a given table (along with an ID for a single row) and have the data returned. BUT I want any field that is a look up to automatically get the lookup data too.

I have established relationships for the lookup fields but would like my code to automatically look for any relationship established on each field.

Is this possible?

--

For example, I have a 'jobs' table with a few lookup fields to other tables:

```
id
description
job_type_id
repro_status_id
job_status_id
customer_id
supplier_id
...
```

Then I have my model for a 'Job' and have used Laravel's convention for creating the relationships:

```
class Job extends BaseModel {

  public function jobStatus (){
    return $this->belongsTo('JobStatus', 'job_status_id');
  }
  public function jobType (){
    return $this->belongsTo('JobType', 'job_type_id');
  }
  public function customer (){
    return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'customer_id');
  }
  // etc...
}
```

So, having established those relationships it would be helpful to be able get the relationship based on fieldname. Something like...

```
// Made up code
Job::getRelationshipByFieldname('job_type_id'); // Returns the jobType method
```

And the reason I want to do this: I'm building a list of form fields for the 'jobs' table but need to catch any relationships on any fields.

Comment: Thanks @JarekTkaczyk - have updated.

Comment: If you follow Laravel's naming conventions, typically if you're relating on `job_type_id` you're either naming the relation `JobType` or `JobTypes`, so you could call `method_exists` on the singular and plural names. Not the best option (I'm sure something can be done with Reflection) but a possible one

Comment: @BenHull so basically you would like to load the relations automatically, right?

Comment: Thanks for comments. @JarekTkaczyk, I guess that's what I want yeah. Antonio's answer below sums it up just right. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, there is no such thing in Laravel, but if your columns follows some pattern and/or Laravel's naming convention, you can create a method on your base model:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public function getRelationshipByFieldname($field)
    {
        // Converts job_status_id into jobStatus

        $method = camel_case(substr($field, 0, strlen($field) - 3));

        return call_user_func(static::class . '::' . $method);
    }

}
```

And if you cannot stick to a convention, you can always map the methods in your base model:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    private $relationMethods = [
        'job_status_id' => 'jobStatus',
        'job_type_id' => 'jobType',
        'customer_id' => 'customer',
    ];

    public function getRelationshipByFieldname($field)
    {
        $method = camel_case($this->relationMethods[$field]);

        return call_user_func(static::class . '::' . $method);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification here. I had begun to head down the route of using an array to store a field to function mapping so I shall keep going that way. Thanks.